# load more comment in rails use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to load more comments but it is not working as I wanted, I've checked the console, it is showing no change, here is the code for my `_post.html.erb`:

```
<div class="posts-wrapper">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-head">
      <div class="thumb-img"></div>
      <div class="user-name">
        <%= post.user.name %>
        <span class="badge"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %></span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="image center-block">
      <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium), class:'img-responsive'), post_path(post) %>
    </div>
    <div class="post-bottom">
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="user-name">
          <%= post.user.name %>
        </div>
        <span class="label label-info">caption:</span><span style="color: black"><%= post.caption %></span>
      </div>
      <div class="comments" id="comments_<%= post.id %>">
        <% if post.comments.any? %>
            <div class="paginator" id="comments-paginator-<%= post.id %>">
              <% unless post.comments.count <= 4 %>
                  <%= link_to "view all #{post.comments.count} comments", post_comments_path(post), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', data: {post_id: "#{post.id}", type: "html"} %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <%= render post.comments.last(4), post: post %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="comment-like-form row">
      <div class="like-button col-sm-1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-form col-sm-11">
        <%= form_for([post, post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...',class: "form-control comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{post.id}"%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is `_comment.html.erb`

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="user-name">
    <% if comment.user %>
        <%= comment.user.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-content">
    <%= comment.content %>
    <span class="label label-warning"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)%></span>
  </div>
  <% if comment.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to post_comment_path(post, comment),id:"post#{post.id}comment#{comment.id}", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },remote: true do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and here is `comment_controller`

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_post
      def index
        @comments = @post.comments.order("created_at ASC")

        respond_to do |format|

          format.html { render :layout => !request.xhr? }

        end
      end
      def create
        @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id

        if @comment.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
            format.js
          end
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Check the comment form, something went wrong."
          render posts_path
        end
      end
      def destroy
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

        @comment.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
          format.js
        end
        # flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
        # redirect_to posts_path
      end

      private

      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
      end

      def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      end
    end

and here is post controller
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post,only: [:edit,:show,:update,:destroy]
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy,:new]
    before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
        # @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js

            format.json { render json: @projects }
        end
    end
    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end
    def create
        if @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
            redirect_to posts_path
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
            render :new
        end
    end
    def show

    end
    def destroy

        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    end
    def edit

    end
    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            flash[:success] = "Post updated."
            redirect_to posts_path
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Update failed.  Please check the form."
            render :edit
        end
    end
    private
    def owned_post
        unless current_user == @post.user
            flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
    def set_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
    end
end
```

and here is JavaScript in asset to load more comment `loadmorecomment.js`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.more-comments').click( function() {
        // alert("ok roi day");

        $(this).on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var postId = $(this).data("post-id");

            $("#comments_" + postId).html(data);

            $("#comments-paginator-" + postId).html("<a id='more-comments' data-post-id=" + postId + " data-type='html' data-remote='true' href='/posts/" + postId + "/comments'>show more comments</a>");
            console.log("<a id='more-comments' data-post-id=" + postId + " data-type='html' data-remote='true' href='/posts/" + postId + "/comments'>show more comments</a>");
        });
    });
});
```

but when I click nothing happens, but in the console it says:

```
Started GET "/posts/25/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-12 18:39:49 +0700
Processing by CommentsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"25"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 25], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering comments/index.html.erb
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC  [["post_id", 25]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 53], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.erb [5 times] (14.1ms)
  Rendered comments/index.html.erb (16.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 17.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: That is a lot code, is there no way it can be reduced to make it easier to view?

Comment: i dont know how,cant i post my git,you can view for me,thanks

Comment: https://github.com/huyanh10tin/studyruby1